# Regex matching of numbers in R

Tags: regex, r

I'm learning regex matching in R using `stringr` package, but I don't understand why

```
str_match("1,000,222.333 /month", "[\\d,]*\\.?\\d*")
     [,1]          
[1,] "1,000,222.333"
```

returns desired result, while

```
str_match("about $1,000,222.33 em's", "[\\d,]*\\.?\\d*")
     [,1]
[1,] ""
```

returns empty string? Is something wrong with my`[\\d,]*`?

I learned that number regex matching is complicated, so this snippet is not supposed to used in production, I just want to understand why it fails in this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `+` to match one or more characters rather than `*` which matches 0 or more.

```
 str_match(v1, "[\\d,]+\\.?\\d*")
 #    [,1]           
 #[1,] "1,000,222.33" 
 #[2,] "1,000,222.333"
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c("about $1,000,222.33 em's", "1,000,222.333 /month")
```

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate, the problem is the `*` operator. Since this operator allows the regular expression engine to match zero or more characters, `[\d,]*` tells the engine to match zero or more digits or the literal character `,` — which might be none at all. I would write this as follows:

```
str_match(x, '[\\d,]+(?:\\.\\d+)?')
```

Or make effective use of [`rm_number`](http://trinker.github.io/qdapRegex_dev/rm_number.html) ( a regex I wrote for this ) from the **qdapRegex** package:

```
library(qdapRegex)

x <- c("about $1,000,222.33 em's", "1,000,222.333 /month")
rm_number(x, extract=TRUE)

# [[1]]
# [1] "1,000,222.33"

# [[2]]
# [1] "1,000,222.333"
```